# Раздельно или с дефисом?

Tags: раздельно-дефис, дефис

*Объектом исследований были выбраны **самцы гамадрилы**.

Для экспериментов отбирались **самцы долгожители**.*

В [**справочнике Розенталя**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111) говорится, что дефис не ставится, "если однословное приложение может быть по значению приравнено к определению-прилагательному: *красавец мужчина* (ср.: *красивый мужчина*), *старик отец, гигант завод*...".
Также дефис не ставится, "если в сочетании двух нарицательных существительных первое обозначает родовое понятие, а второе — видовое: *цветок хризантема, дерево эвкалипт*...".

Кажется, что эти правила не подходят к "самцам": их вроде бы не заменишь на определение "самцовый" и к родовому понятию не отнесёшь. Как всё-таки правильно писать такие сочетания?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оба сочетания пишутся через дефис. Правило примерно следующее:
Если есть одиночные приложение и определяемое слово, без именных в паре, то дефис ставится всегда, кроме 5-ти пунктов:

**1. Первое слово заменяется прилагательным.**
Существительное, которое идет первым, заменяется прилагательным, как ‟малютка сын” заменяется ‟маленький сын”. В ваших сочетаниях первые слова не заменяются такими прилагательными.

**2. Род-вид отношения существительных.**
Род-вид отношения, как в логике: цветок мальва, гриб лисичка. Но есть исключения, обычно из научной и другой специальной лексики, которые все же пишутся с дефисом: жук-плавунец, рак-отшельник, слесарь-инструментальщик, химик-органик. В ваших сочетаниях нет таких род-вид отношений.

**3. Сочетания со словами: гражданин, господин, товарищ.**
Вот пара примеров: гражданин посол, товарищ майор. В ваших сочетаниях нет таких слов.

**4. Пояснение из одного слова.**
Когда предложение прерывается, делается отступление с информацией из одного слов (данное правило про одиночные приложение и определяемое слово), и предложение продолжается, — все это с соответствующей интонацией отступления. Вот пример такого приложения: ‟Отца, пьяницу, кормила с малых лет, и сама себя”. В ваших сочетаниях нет приложений с пояснительным значением.
**5. Особый вид отношений с тире.**
В предложениях вроде: ‟Я не слишком люблю это дерево — осину”, ‟Было ещё одно препятствие на пути учёных — суеверие островитян”, ‟Профессия его была самая мирная — учитель”. То есть когда сначала что-то обозначается более общим словом, а потом, после паузы, как при двоеточии, это же обозначается менее общим словом. Такие предложения в справочнике Розенталя находятся в теме про пояснительные конструкции, но, на мой взгляд, это является крайне грубой ошибкой в построении терминологии и пояснение и вот это вот следует разделять. В ваших сочетаниях нет такого рода приложений.

**Вывод:** согласно данной формализации, оба сочетания пишутся через дефис.

Comment: Р.п. — гамадрил**а** (так что "работники завода" не в тему). То есть там самцы и гамадрилы.

Comment: Ну вы даёте! 1. *В сочетании ‟самцы гамадрилы” отношения с родительным падежом...* Гамадрил (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB) — слово мужского рода. С родительным падежом — самцы гамадрилов. 2. *...дефис ставится всегда, кроме 5-ти пунктов...* Пять — это количественное числительное. Наращение ошибочно.

Comment: Спасибо, что поправили. Что касается наращений, то это какая-то грамотейская пакость. Я решительно отвергаю эту норму.

Comment: Связано оно с тем, что 5 расшифровывается как "пять" (так и у вас), но никак не как "пятый" (на это нужно указать наращением), а падеж роли не играет.

Comment: А как слово ‟пяти” зашифровывается в цифру с приращением?

Comment: Наращения в принципе используются только с порядковыми числительными! "5-ти" — это грубая ошибка!

Comment: Это контринтуитивная и бессмысленная норма. Следовать этой норме — грубая ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!